# Returning object from promise function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the list created with the value received from API to where it was called. I'm using Promise to make sure the function returns the value after it gets the value from calling API. To better explain with the code, I have a function `callAPI` that calls `getNamedEntity`. Ultimately, I want `callAPI` to receive the result of `request.post()` in `getNamedEntity`. However, I get Promise object and undefined when I test with `console.log("outside " + result)` and `console.log("inside doRequest " + result)` inside each function respectively.

```
function callAPI(text) {
    const result = getNamedEntity(text);
    console.log("outside " + result);
}
```

```
async function getNamedEntity(text) {
  var requestJson = {
      ...
  };

  var options = {
      ...
  };

  function doRequest(options) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      request.post(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          const result = resolve(body);
          console.log("inside doRequest " + result);
        } else {
          reject(error);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  doRequest(options)
    .then((body) => {
      var entityList = [];
      const obj = JSON.parse(body);
      const words = obj.return_object.sentence[0].NE;
      for (var word of words) {
        entityList.push(word.text);
      }
      return entityList;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

```
outside [object Promise]
inside doRequest undefined
```

Comment: Well, one issue is that `async` returns a promise so you need to `await` the call to `getNamedEntity` in `callApi`, or use `then`.

Comment: @Andy I get syntax error `await is only valid in async function` when I change to `await getNamedEntity(text)` inside `callAPI` perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Change it to `return doRequest(options)...` and use `getNamedEntity(text).then(console.log)`

Answer (score 0):

`console.log("outside " + result)` returns a promise object cause you forgot to `await` the `getNamedEntity(text);` or, alternately, put the `console.log` inside a `.then`, like `getNamedEntity(text).then(result => console.log(result));`

`console.log("inside doRequest " + result);` returns undefined because the `resolve` function returns void, ie, it returns nothing.  Change to `console.log("inside doRequest " + body);` or move the `console.log` into the `.then((body)` portion.

Comment: I get syntax error `await is only valid in async function` when I change to `await getNamedEntity(text)` inside `callAPI` perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: correct, either that function also needs to be `async` or you use the `.then` method.   Those new to promises say that async or promises "infect" their code.  But basically where `await` sits is where the function ends and the rest of the function is basically a separate callback function